# How do I bypass outlook alerts when trying to get user infromation?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to get username, user email, user department, and user location from outlook to populate an excel user form.

That code works without issue.  The problem I am having is this: I get the popup from Excel saying "A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in Outlook.  If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up to date."

I found some code that is supposed to suppress this popup, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Below is the procedure that is calling using the procedure. I have put the call to the "Turn_Auto_Yes_On" procedure multiple times to see if it works with any of the calls.  Turn_Auto_yes_On is successfully executed, but seems to have no effect as I still get the outlook message after execution.

I am stuck here and have gone to multiple sites for answers, and I have found none.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Function fill_Outlook_Info() As Boolean


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call Turn_Auto_Yes_On
    Set OL = CreateObject("outlook.application")

    Call Turn_Auto_Yes_On
    Set olAllUsers = OL.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries

    Call Turn_Auto_Yes_On
    s_OutlookUser = OL.Session.CurrentUser.Name

    Call Turn_Auto_Yes_On
    Set oentry = olAllUsers.Item(s_OutlookUser)

    Call Turn_Auto_Yes_On
    Set oExchUser = oentry.GetExchangeUser() 
    v_department = oExchUser.DEPARTMENT
    v_Email = oExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    s_OutlookCity = oExchUser.city
End Function
```

and this is the code that is supposed to bypass outlook's alerts

```
Option Explicit

'these declarations are to access the RegisterWindowsMessage which is used to send "yes" to outlook

Public OL, olAllUsers, oExchUser, oentry As Object
Public v_Email As Variant 'v_department
'Public s_OutlookUser As String
Public Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage Lib "User32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, _
ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long



Public Sub Turn_Auto_Yes_On()

Dim wnd As Long
Dim uClickYes As Long
Dim Res As Long
   uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
   wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
   Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 1, 0)
End Sub

Public Sub Turn_Off_Auto_Yes()
Dim wnd As Long
Dim uClickYes As Long
Dim Res As Long
   uClickYes = RegisterWindowMessage("CLICKYES_SUSPEND_RESUME")
   wnd = FindWindow("EXCLICKYES_WND", 0&)
   Res = SendMessage(wnd, uClickYes, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe the code ultimately works, maybe not.  One thing is certain though: it's a workaround, and a klunky one at that.  What it does is it clicks the "Confirm"/Yes" button for you when you call the code, so I suppose you must call the routine every time Outlook has a security prompt open.  A better solution is to use e.g. vbMAPI or Redemption, which solve this thing the proper way.

Comment: I'm guessing it's in macro security settings.  Check out the section "View security settings in the Trust Center" in this [MS Docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-e-mail-address-information-or-sending-e-mail-on-my-behalf-df007135-c632-4ae4-8577-dd4ba26750a2)

Comment: @CarlColjin Yes, it's very klunky, and I know it.  I'll look into both vbMAPI or redemption.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

While not specific to this exact use case, I have gotten around similar outlook "manual confirmation" and "Outlook security" issues by using [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm).

> Outlook Redemption works around limitations imposed by the Outlook Security Patch plus provides a number of objects and functions to work with properties and functionality not exposed through the Outlook object model.
>
> With Outlook Redemption you can [...] Make your code runs unaffected by the Security Patch.

My particular use case was automatically sending outlook e-mails from python. I had the same issue with the user pop-up and this did the trick.